# How to make bat file listing with options to choose

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to make a bat file that list all of the files in a specific directory, and add numbers at the beginning of the every one of the listed items. This numbers need to be a selectable options.

Example:
I have a folder with 5 files in it, aaa.exe, bbb.exe, ccc.exe, ddd.exe, eee.exe. When i run bat file i need to see

> 1. aaa.exe
> 2. bbb.exe
> 3. ccc.exe
> 4. ddd.exe
> 5. eee.exe

So now if i wana run 5-th exe i need to press 5, than press enter and that 5th exe will now start.

I allredy find how to list all of the items in folder with this code

```
REM -start "c:\windows\system32" notepad.exe 
for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
pause
exit
```

but i can't figure out how to add numbers in front of the text and make that numbers to be a selectable options.

Edit---

Now im getting

> ERROR: Duplicate choices are not allowed. running '""' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

when i'm trying to run this loop for a second time.

This is code that i wrote:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


REM ---Prompt part
:choise
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Install programs (Y/[N])?  
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" EQU "Y" GOTO :chooseInstall
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" EQU "N" GOTO :nope

REM --Cheking for Y or N
GOTO :choise

:nope
echo "Ok. Have a nice daty / night"
pause
exit



:chooseInstall
echo Wich program do you wana install ?
echo.
echo 1. 7Zip
echo 2. CPU Z
echo.

SET /P AREYOUSURE=Choosing: 
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" EQU "1" set "pathToSoft=C:\Users\usr\Desktop\hello"
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" EQU "2" set "pathToSoft=C:\Users\usr\Desktop\bye"


echo.
echo.

echo %pathToSoft%

echo.
echo.


REM ---Installs
echo "Wich file to install"

cd %pathToSoft%
echo.
echo.



REM --Loops that scan files

set /A counter=0


for /R %%i in (*) do (

if not "%%~nxi" == "%~nx0" (
    set /A counter+=1
    echo !counter!: %%~nxi
    set exe[!counter!]=%%i
    set choice=!choice!!counter!
    )
)

if %counter% LSS 10 (
choice /C %choice% /M "Choose: "
set EXENUM=!ERRORLEVEL!
) else set /P EXENUM="enter exe number: "


set EXECUTABLE=!exe[%EXENUM%]!
echo running %EXECUTABLE%
call "%EXECUTABLE%"

echo.
echo.
echo.





:installmore
SET /P INSTALLMORE=Do you wana install somthing else (Y/[N])?  
IF /I "%INSTALLMORE%" EQU "Y" GOTO :chooseInstall
IF /I "%INSTALLMORE%" EQU "N" GOTO :nope
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- count the executables and associate them with the counter, creating kind of "array" variables (filter out the current batch script)
- build the choice list at the same time
- after the loop, use `choice` if no more than 9 choices, else use a classical interactive `set`
- retrieve the user selection and call the executable/batch file

(you have to enable delayedexpansion to be able to use `%` and `!` env. var separators & instant evaluation within the loop)

can be done like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /A counter=0
set choice=

for /R %%i in (*) do (

if not "%%~nxi" == "%~nx0" (
set /A counter+=1
echo !counter!: %%~nxi
set exe[!counter!]=%%i

set choice=!choice!!counter!
)
)

if %counter% LSS 10 (
choice /C %choice% /M "type exe number"
set EXENUM=!ERRORLEVEL!
) else set /P EXENUM="enter exe number: "


set EXECUTABLE=!exe[%EXENUM%]!
echo running %EXECUTABLE%
call "%EXECUTABLE%"
```

Comment: Got beaten... Great answer to make use of arrays. I thought about that and came to the conclusion that I have no idea how to do that in batch... Quick note: `choice` will immediately take the input as typed and will not wait for a Return.

Comment: Thanx allot. For now it works perfect!
I do a slight change in this line: "for /R %%i in (*.exe) do ("
i remove .exe and everything starts to work like magick.
Thanx again. Have a good day :)

Comment: it's not really an array actually. It's just a name built with square brackets. But the illusion is almost perfect.

Comment: ok, edited to remove `.exe` extensions so you can call `.com` files. BTW maybe you want to use `call` prefix if you want to stay in your script when running `.bat` executables.

Comment: I find one problem.  It count from 1 to 9 but if there is a 10-th file it give me error: Duplicate Choices are not allowed.

Comment: edited with 2 modes. Now you can select even if there are more than 9 files.

Comment: It's good now. Only problem is if file that it need to be run is under folder that have space in it's name :D Do you have time to fix it ?

btw тhanx for your effort.

Comment: I edit my first post and post full code. But now im getting error again when loop starting second time.